# XPath query search

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Such structure is given

```
<div class="user-number">123</div>
<div class="user-state">
<span class="u-state-icon icon icon-1"></span>
<span> User1</span>
</div>
```

I've tried such (incorrect) xpath for locating `User1` by `user-number` and do not understand where is the problem..

```
xpath=//*[@class='user-number' and text() = '123']/following-sibling::*[contains(@class,'user-state')]/descendant::*[contains(@text,'User1')]
```

What is the best way to debug it?
For example, if

```
xpath=//*[@class='user-number' and text() = '123']/following-sibling::*[contains(@class,'user-state')]
```

locates some element - how to print out its text property - to check which element is actually located?

Comment: looks like I found the answer //*[@class='user-number' and text() = '123']/following-sibling::*[contains(@class,'user-state')]/span[text() = ' User1']  But the best way for debug is still the question))

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath expression is, surely, incorrect - `@text` should be replaced with `text()` (or just `.`):

```
//*[@class='user-number' and . = '123']/following-sibling::*[contains(@class,'user-state')]/descendant::*[contains(.,'User1')]
```

Debugging xpath expressions is usually done using the browser developer tools: in the firebug, or inside a browser console. For instance, in the google-chrome console, you can execute the following:

```
$x("//*[@class='user-number' and . = '123']/following-sibling::*[contains(@class,'user-state')")
```

And see if there is a match.

Or, you can also debug it inside your code. For example (using `python`), find the first `div` element and print out it's text:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='user-number' and . = '123']")
print(element.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The meta-question is, how to debug XPath expressions?

Well, for simple ones like these, it's really best to just stare at them till you see the problem. Check the spelling of names, check namespaces, check whitespace issues. At least it's easier than debugging regular expressions.

For more complex XPaths, try breaking them up. Remove a predicate and see if that makes a difference. Or work in reverse, build up the path expression by adding conditions, checking at each stage that it still finds something.

If you're really seriously into XPath, consider schema-aware processing: this will match your XPath expression against a schema to make sure it makes sense.

Consider using a visual XPath processor for debugging. There are a number around. I use the XPath processor in oXygen (though not really for debugging the XPath, more for discovering the content of the document, but those tasks often need to be done together.)